# Carto SQL fails due to CORS error in local CartoDB?

Tags: carto, sql, carto-js, cors

I have successfully installed CartoDB in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and uploaded a point geometry dataset. I have created a HTML/JS application to access the layers from the local cartodb and visualize in the leaflet client application using cartodb.createLayer.

I need to display a chart by using the data from the uploaded layer. When I try using CartoDB SQL API, I get the CORS error. The details are below.

Can you let me know whether we need to include any configuration for CORS in local cartoDB?

**Code:**

```
$.getJSON('http://development.localhost.lan:3000/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM tablename & api_key = 1a77a491a96dff1c380fc869498587db105c5b65', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data.rows, function(key, val) {
    // do something!
  });
});
```

**Error:**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://development.localhost.lan:3000/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22qgis_view_standard_all_permits_processed_current%22%20&%20api_key%20=%201a77a491a96dff1c380fc869498587db105c5b65.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got resolved. The actual error was 2 things as described below.

**Error 1 :** The URL for accessing SQL API was wrong. The Correct URL is "*http://development.localhost.lan:**8080**/api/v1/sql*"

**Error 2 :** The access to the dataset was private. When I change to "**public**" I could access the query result.

But I am not sure why the private dataset is not accessible even though I give api_key along with the query

Comment: Hi Dinesh, do you mind marking the issue then as solved?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL API works for private dataset too when the api_key is sent along with the URL without any spaces in the URL as below.

```
http://development.localhost.lan:8080/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM tablename&api_key=1a77a491a96dff1c380fc869498587db105c5b65
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to circumvent CORS errors in a local installation is to use domainless URLs like http://local-installation/user/username/: https://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#domainless-urls
If the cartoDB and the webserver can share the same hostname and port.